# Android studio 4.1.3 unable to locate ABD

Tags: android

Good day I recently had a hard drive crash. I have since installed android studio 4.1.3. On the previous version of Android Studio I had no problems running the apks and debugging on my current phone.

With this version 4.1.3 I just can not get it working. I have tried the various solutions on stack and other sites :

1. deleting the platform tools folder and reinstalling
2. adding abd.exe to system path
3. installing samsung drivers, installing intel drivers for the phone
4. Only thing I could not try was setting the project SDK according to this link https://superuser.com/questions/1419201/unable-to-locate-adb-when-using-android-studio/1561048#1561048 as my version 4.1.3 does not follow the project structure mentioned.

Im using windows 7 64bit. Can some confirm they are using windows 7 and 4.1.3 and do not have this issue? Any other suggestions on solving?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was actually related to the incorrect USB driver being installed.